# How to fire a function with Search button as well as the Enter button on keyboard in Angular JS?

Tags: search, enter

I have a Search field which currently fires when the Search button is clicked after a text input is given in the field. The code is as following:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Search" ng-model="searchkey">
</div>
<button type="submit" ng-click="searchfunc(searchkey)">
  Search
</button>
```

How do I fire this Search through the Enter key on the keyboard as well when an input is entered on the Search field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Search" ng-model="searchkey" ng-keydown="myFunc($event)">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.myFunc = function(keyEvent) {
  if (keyEvent.which === 13) {
    // do stuff
    // here you can call the function and pass a parameter: "searchfunc($scope.searchkey);"
  }
}
```

Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Sj4ZU/62/

Comment: @Pares, what exactly doesn't work? any errors in console?

Comment: @Pares, I have updated the answer with the working fiddle (type something in `input` and press enter).

Comment: Thanks Commercial Suicide. The fiddle is working but I'm trying to call my function and that is not working... so something like this.$scope.myFunc = function(keyEvent) {
  if (keyEvent.which === 13) {
    // do stuff
     $scope.searchfunc(searchkey);"
  }
}

Comment: @Pares, did you declare `$scope.searchfunc`? and it's a function? something like `$scope.searchfunc = function(parameter) {//do stuff here};`?

Comment: Hi Commercial...yeah I have declared it like this                  $scope.searchfunc=function(searchkey) { //it goes to a search results page}search key is coming from ng model of the input text in my html.  So in the myFunc I'm now trying to use the same searchkey like $scope.searchfunc(searchkey)

Comment: @Pares, Hmm. Sorry, I can't say more without looking at your controller's code. I believe you can fix the issue by yourself if you will use `console.log`s to debug and will read the code attentively.

Comment: $scope.myFunc = function (keyEvent) {
        if (keyEvent.which === 13) {
            $scope.searchfunc($scope.searchkey);        }
    }

I have used Commericial Suicide's answer with a modification. was just missing a scope in calling the defined function searchfunc.

Comment: @Pares, looks like, you found a final working solution, cool, I am proud of you ;)